# How to detect code duplication during development?

Tags: c++, code-duplication

We have a fairly large code base, 400K LOC of C++, and code duplication is something of a problem. Are there any tools which can effectively detect duplicated blocks of code?

Ideally this would be something that developers could use during development rather than just run occasionally to see where the problems are. It would also be nice if we could integrate such a tool with CruiseControl to give a report after each check in.

I had a look at [Duploc](http://www.iam.unibe.ch/~scg/Research/Duploc/index.html) some time ago, it showed a nice graph but requires a smalltalk environment to use it, which makes running it automatically rather difficult.

Free tools would be nice, but if there are some good commercial tools I would also be interested.

Comment: Whenever somebody uses the paste button :-}

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490884/why-is-copy-and-paste-of-code-dangerous

Answer (score 40):

[Simian](http://www.harukizaemon.com/simian/) detects duplicate code in C++ projects.

Update: Also works with Java, C#, C, COBOL, Ruby, JSP, ASP, HTML, XML, Visual Basic, Groovy source code and even plain text files

Comment: would simian check seamlessly .mm files, AKA ObjectiveC++

Comment: @rraallvv Simian can do plain text checks, so it can detect code duplication in any language.

Comment: Note that it's not free for commercial use.

Comment: It does not seem to be working recursively if I just run it with the default settings on a directory in Linux.

Comment: I followed the link but the installation instructions do not show how to download it.

Answer (score 21):

I've used [PMD's Copy-and-Paste-Detector](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.2.5/cpd.html) and integrated it into CruiseControl by using the following wrapper script (be sure to have the pmd jar in the classpath).

Our check runs nightly. If you wish to limit output to list only files from the current change set you might need some custom programming (idea: check all and list only duplicates where one of the changed files is involved. You have to check all files because a change could use some code from a non-changed file). Should be doable by using XML output and parsing the result. Don't forget to post that script when it's done ;)

For starters the "Text" output should be ok, but you will want to display the results in a user-friendly way, for which i use a perl script to generate HTML files from the "xml" output of CPD. Those are accessible by posting them to the tomcat where cruise's reporting jsp resides. The developers can view them from there and see the results of their dirty hacking :)

It runs quite fast, less than 2 seconds on 150 KLoc code (empty lines and comments not counted in that number).

**duplicatecheck.xml**:

```xml
<project name="duplicatecheck" default="cpd">

<property name="files.dir" value="dir containing your sources"/>
<property name="output.dir" value="dir containing results for publishing"/>

<target name="cpd">
    <taskdef name="cpd" classname="net.sourceforge.pmd.cpd.CPDTask"/>
    <cpd minimumTokenCount="100" 
         language="cpp" 
         outputFile="${output.dir}/duplicates.txt"
         ignoreLiterals="false"
         ignoreIdentifiers="false"
         format="text">
        <fileset dir="${files.dir}/">
            <include name="**/*.h"/>
            <include name="**/*.cpp"/>
                <!-- exclude third-party stuff -->
            <exclude name="boost/"/>
            <exclude name="cppunit/"/>
        </fileset>
    </cpd>
</target>
```

Comment: Be sure to use the latest version from the sourgeforge page! Their documentation page suggests a version from 2011, while there is active development. In my case version 5.5 works much better than the version 4.2 they link on their homepage.

Comment: There is no mention of C++ support in their documentation anymore either.

Comment: The latest link to PMD's duplicate code page is https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_cpd.html#supported-languages

Answer (score 7):

[duplo](http://duplo.giants.ch/) appears to be a C implementation of the algorithm used in Duploc. It is simple to compile and install, and while the options are limited it seems to more or less work out-of-the-box.

Comment: I just tried it on a rather legacy code file with lots of tons-of-almost-dupes, and compared to a recent code file with few-perfect-dupes. The legacy file was rated perfect. The new file was rated bad.

Answer (score 6):

These Debian packages seem to do *something* along these lines:

- [similarity-tester](http://packages.debian.org/sid/similarity-tester) (also known as [the software and text similarity tester SIM](http://dickgrune.com/Programs/similarity_tester/))
- [simhash](http://packages.debian.org/sid/simhash)

P.S. There ought to be a [debtags](http://debtags.debian.net) tag for all tools related for finding [near] duplication. (But what would it be called?)

Comment: Perfect answer. Package `similarity-tester` has comprehensive man page `man 1 sim`, works out of the box, and produces convincing results.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the [PMD project](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/).

I've never used it, but have always wanted to.

Comment: I thought that PMD was just for Java, but I now see that CPD (which is part of PMD) can be used for C++ as well.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can run a clone detector on your source
code base every night.

*Many clone detectors work by comparing source lines,
and can only find exact duplicate code.*

CCFinder, above, works by comparing language
tokens, so it isn't sensitive to white space
changes.  It can detect clones which are variants
of the original code if there only single token
changes (e.g, change a variable X to Y in 
the clone).

*Ideally what you want is the above, but the ability
to find clones where
the variations are allowed to be relatively arbitrary,
e.g., replace a variable by an expression, a statement
by a block, etc.*

Our CloneDR clone detector does this for Java, C#, C++, COBOL, VB.net, VB6, Fortran and a variety
of other languages.  It can be seen at:
http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/Clone/index.html

As well as being able to handle multiple languages, CloneDR engine is capable of handling a variety of input encoding styles, including ASCII, ISO-8859-1, UTF8, UTF16, EBCDIC, a number of Microsoft encodings, and (Japanese) Shift-JIS.

The site has several clone detection run example reports, including one for C++.

EDIT Feb 2014:  Now handles all of C++14.

Answer (score 2):

[CCFinderX](http://www.ccfinder.net/ccfinderx.html) is a free (for in-house use) cloned code detector that supports multiple programming languages (Java, C, C++, COBOL, VB, C#).

Comment: Thanks for this link. I will definitely  look at it. What is even better is that there is a Japanese version (all other developers on the project apart from me are Japanese)

Answer (score 2):

Same (http://sourceforge.net/projects/same/) is extremely plain, but it works on text lines instead of tokens, which is useful if you're using a language that isn't supported by one of the fancier clone finders.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Simian](http://www.redhillconsulting.com.au/products/simian/) which supports Java, C#, C++, C, Objective-C, JavaScript...

It's supported by *Hudson* (like CPD).

Unless you're an open source project, you must *pay* for Simian.

Answer (score 2):

[ConQAT](https://www.conqat.org/) is a great tool  which suports C++ code analysis. Can find duplicates ignoring whitespace. Has extreamly handy gui and console interfaces. 
Because of it's flexibility it is not an easy to to setup. I've found [this blog post very useful for setting up c++ project](http://amr-noaman.blogspot.com/2013/04/detect-exact-and-similar-code.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use our [SourceMeter](https://www.sourcemeter.com/) tool for detecting code duplication. It is a command line tool (very similar to compilers), so you can it easily integrate into continuous integration tools, like [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) your mentioned, or [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/).

Comment: SourceMeter is free, but is quite unfriendly during setup, or probably it just doesn't support VS2019 with v142

Answer (score 1):

Finding "identical" code snippets is relatively easy, there are existing tool that already do this (see other answers).

Sometimes it's a good thing, sometimes it's not; it can bog down development time if done at a too fine "level"; i.e. trying to refactor so much code, you loose your goal (and probably bust your milestones and schedules).

What is harder is to find multiple function/method that do the same thing but with different (but similar) inputs and/or algorithm without proper documentation.

If you have to two or different methods to do the same thing and the programmer try to fix one instance but forget (or does not know they exist)  to fix the other ones, you will increase the risk to your software.

Comment: ... and as a practical matter, you aren't going to be able to detect that two pieces of code *do* the same thing if they are implemented differently.  There's a Turing machine standing in your way.

Comment: "What is harder is to find multiple function/method that do the same thing but with different (but similar) inputs and/or algorithm without proper documentation."

Right. 

And if they DO the same thing, they should be NAMED the same, since the name should describe why that code exists in the first place.

So step one might be to make sure that all functions/methods are accurately named and documented. If the name truly describes what it does, similarities and identities will quickly become obvious.

Comment: Trouble is, even a "does the same thing" oracle (which I believe to be significantly more powerful than a halting oracle?) wouldn't help you figure out if two names express (or are intended to express) the same idea. (Besides which, there would tend to be a lot of false positives.)

Answer (score -3):

[TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) has a powerful code duplication engine for .NET and java, that can effortlessly run as part of your build system.

Comment: Neither .Net or Java is C++, so while this may be effortless to run, it is also fruitless.