# Find similar blocks of texts

Tags: duplicates, longest-substring

I'm trying to extract (long) repeating blocks of the same code, and have the regular flow of execution jump to/from those block when needed.
This is done over an [educational assembly language called Hack](http://www.nand2tetris.org/).
How can I  extract those blocks.
I understand it's an instance of longest-common-subsequence problem, but I don't see how to approach this.
I have seen, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908139/i-need-a-tool-to-find-duplicates-or-similar-blocks-of-text-in-a-singular-text-fi), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908139/i-need-a-tool-to-find-duplicates-or-similar-blocks-of-text-in-a-singular-text-fi), and a couple other - no help.

Any pointers, be they -- solution course, relevant reads, or even libraries -- are much appreciated.

Comment: If possible, let's move this question to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398565/generic-code-duplication-detection-tool (also language agnostic)